# How to put a string inside a JPanel?

Tags: user-interface, text

My partner has  JScrollPane made and all i want to do is display a line of String/Text from another class on top of it.

Any idea how to do that?

The seperate class has a getText method inside of it but i cant seem to add it in.

Answer (score 0):

Incomplete details brother.

Your question heading mentions "string inside `JPanel`"?
You want to write a string over `JScrollPane`? As far as I know JScrollPane is a container that shows scroll bars on run-time if required.

Are you trying to write string over a `JTextArea`?

Comment: Oh hey thanks for the help, i kinda figured it out myself using.

  JLabel myLabel = new JLabel ( class.getName());
  myLabelLabel.setAlignmentX(0);
  scrollPanel.add(myLabel);